# How to do operations with form values?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, snmp, oid

so i have a form with 3 text fields, in two of them, users enters a code (and OID), which i use to run a command (snmpbulkwalk). So i want to store the outputs of those commands in a variable, lets say var1 and var2.

[[image]]

But then, in the last text field, i want to do and operation with these variables, like: var1 - var2.

So far i tried this:

```
    @var1 = "nice -n 19 snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c %snmp_community 
    %sensor_ip "+ "#{monitor_category_params[:oid].strip}"+" | awk 
    '/kB$/{ $(NF-1)= $(NF-1)*1024;} {print $0}'  | sed 's/ [A-Za- 
    z]*$//' | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' | paste -s 
    -d';' -"
    puts("var1 = " + "#{@var1}");

    @var2 = "nice -n 19 snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c %snmp_community 
    %sensor_ip "+ "#{monitor_category_params[:oid2]}"+" | awk 
    '/kB$/{ $(NF-1)= $(NF-1)*1024;} {print $0}'  | sed 's/ [A-Za- 
    z]*$//' | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' | paste -s 
    -d';' -"
    puts("var2 = " + "#{@var2}");

    @var3 = "#{monitor_category_params[:snmp_oper].strip}"
    puts("var3 with {} = " + "#{@var3}");
    system = '$(#{@var3})'
    puts(system(system));
```

The thing is i dont know how to store the output of the shell command "nice -n 19 ...blabla" in the variable. I used exec and backticks like this:

```
   exec "nice -n 19 snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c %snmp_community %sensor_ip "+ "#{monitor_category_params[:oid].strip}"+" | awk '/kB$/{ $(NF-1)= $(NF-1)*1024;} {print $0}'  | sed 's/ [A-Za-z]*$//' | awk '{print $NF}' | grep -o '[[:digit:]]*' | paste -s -d';' -"
```

but it gives me this error, which i dont get it since the command is well formatted.

```
   sh: -c: línea 0: EOF inesperado mientras se buscaba un `)' coincidente
   sh: -c: línea 1: error sintáctico: no se esperaba el final del fichero
```

I dont know if im losing arguments (%snmp_community or %sensor_ip), but the final result should be something like system = number - number. but i only get system = var1 - var2, which is not doing nothing since i want the outputs of the commands, not the name of the variables.

sorry if didnt explain myself good, thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

So assuming this is related with ruby or ruby on rails
@var1 and @var2 are instance variable of a method in some class.
You can directly use the backticks directly to save to output from the shell command

```
@var1 = `ls`
p @var1
```

However, some bash commands do not return a string value directly.

I have not used snmpbulkwalk till now but $PATH might be similar in a way

```
@var1 = `echo $PATH` #add you own shell code here to check
p @var1
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your reply.

right now i only want to focus on storing the output of that command in var1. 

so, right now im using backticks like you said

@var1 = ` command ` 

i think the problem is that im not scaping correctly something inside the backticks, for example:

       @var1 = ` nice -n 19 snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c %snmp_community %sensor_ip ` +  ` #{monitor_category_params[:oid].strip} `

this is telling me that %sensor_ip doesnt exist, so i guess the arguments are not passing?

Comment: In that case, create a string first
 str = ` nice -n 19 snmpbulkwalk -v 2c -c %snmp_community %sensor_ip ` + ` #{monitor_category_params[:oid].strip} `
Then @var1 = `echo str`
Then p @var1

Comment: That doesnt work, problem is the same, it doesnt detect the arguments. If instead of writing %sensor_ip i put the IP and the same with the community, it works, so the problem are the arguments.